# Finding the Schwarzchild radius of a star of solar mass 30

Tags: homework-and-exercises, black-holes

I am currently trying to determine the Schwarzchild radius of a star with solar mass 30. I am calculating it both with respect to solar mass, and w.r.t kilograms, however I am getting conflicting answers. (of a factor of 10)

$$
1 \text{ solar mass} \sim 1.9891 \cdot 10^{31}\,\text{kg}
$$
so I calulated

$$
30\,\text{SM}\sim 5.97 \cdot 10^{32}\,\text{kg}
$$

Using the formula for the Sch Radius:

$$
R_s =\frac{2GM}{c^2}
$$

I determined that you can calculate this using both the solar mass, and the kg mass to confirm.

Using given proportionality constants for $2G/c^2$:

$$
= 2.95\,\text{km/solar mass}\\
= 1.48 \cdot 10^{-27}\,\text{m/kg}
$$

Using the formula above, I have obtained:

$$
\text{using solar mass: }R_s=88.5\,\text{km}\\
\text{using kg: } R_s=883\,\text{km}
$$

If someone could work this out and help me clarify I would be very grateful!

Comment: You will need to show us the details of the two calculations for us to comment usefully.

Comment: WolframAlpha [confirms](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Schwarzschild+radius%2C+mass+%3D+30+solar+masses+) the 88 km number

Answer (score 2):

Your method is correct, but you've got lost in the numbers. This is a good opportunity to use some neat web tools.

---

Google: 30 solar masses

Answer:
30 solar masses =
5.9673 × $10^{31}$ kg

So you have miscalculated your solar masses in kg.

---

Secondly, there is a neat [WolframAlpha tool](http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=15c7a7eb32c8610b005811b8640ebc1):

Given Mass = 30 solar masses

Answer: 88.59 km

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much! This has been frustrating me for a long time! I really appreciate your help! :)